# Open vue subroutes with params from extern website

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router

Is it possible to open an vuejs subroute from an external page with nginx? E.G

https://www.vuejsapp.com/subroute/param123

My current result is redirect to the nginx 404 page.

Thanks for help,
best regards and stay healthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuejs router uses html5 pushstate for routing, which happens only in client side it means when a route changes it has nothing to do with server side and when external request comes to vue, first goes to server side and sees there is not path matching url and returns 404 **so the only thing you should do is** to rewrite all http requests to index.html file in that case server side will send all requests to index.html and then vue js will handle routing and finally your component will be mounted.
if your web server is apache you should do this (rewriting all requests to index.html) in .htaccess file